# Kendo UI Grid freezes when supplied with disabled reactive form group

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm using the kendo ui grid with in-cell editing and supplying an angular reactive form group. In some cases I need to make the form group disabled so the grid is read only. When supplying a disabled form group the grid enters edit mode as read-only but then freezes. Seems like a bug or is unsupported?

```
<kendo-grid [kendoGridInCellEditing]="onCreateFormGroup"
        [removeConfirmation]="onRemoveConfirmation"
        [kendoGridBinding]="users"
        [height]="400"
        [pageSize]="10"
        [pageable]="true"
        [sortable]="true"
        (save)="onSave($event)"
        (cellClose)="onCellClose($event)">
```

and when creating the form group:

```
onCreateFormGroup(args: any) {

let user: User;

if (args.isNew) {
  user = new User()
} else {
  user = User.factory(args.dataItem);
}

const formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: user.id,
  instanceId: user.instanceId,
  state: user.state,
  firstName: [user.firstName, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(250)]],
  lastName: [user.lastName, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(250)]],
  eMail: [user.eMail, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
});

if (!this.canUpdate) {
  formGroup.disable();
}

this.currentFormGroup = formGroup;
return formGroup;
```

}